# Regex an Empty Space in Swift

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I want to regex a string and see if there is an empty space inside it. Unfortunately due to Swift's use of `\` inside double quotes, the code below produces an error.

```
"space here".rangeOfString("\s", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
```

How can I regex to see if an empty space is inside the string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use two backslashes:

```
"space here".rangeOfString("\\s", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
```

(a single backslash is treated as an escape character).